# Text spam upon button press

Tags: python

I have some code that will print when a button is pressed, but it repeats itself so much when the button is pressed, all i need is for the code to go through the iteration once. Whenever i implement the code with a for loop that only does one cycle it still spams multiple times

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

start_pins = [14]
stop_pins = [15]

for pin in start_pins:
  GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
  
for pin in stop_pins:
  GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
  
while True:
  for pin in start_pins:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.LOW:
      print("Pin", pin, " has been pressed")
      
  for pin in stopins:
    if GPIO.input(pin) != GPIO.LOW:
      print("Pin", pin, " has been pressed")
```

Comment: You've set while True: and haven't given any way to set it to false and get out of the loop. set a break pint after the if statement and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also consider putting something like time.sleep(0.2) after each print line, might give you enough time to release the key before the While True tries to fire the print hundred of times, those iterations are very fast

Comment: Glad to hear it. I also posted my comment as an answer if you'd like to mark it as Accepted Answer. Thanks.

Comment: Add some code that stores the last pin states through the loop in a list. On each execution of the loop, compare the pins current state to the last state and, if different, work out the message and print. No need for a `time.sleep` command

Answer (score 0):

Since the iterations are happening very frequently in your While True loop, it may be a good idea to include `time.sleep(0.5)` after each of your print lines, to give you time to release the key before the print would be triggered again by next immediate iteration.